# Showing that Ito integrals of functions form martingales.

Tags: integration, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales

My textbook says that $X_t = (\int_{0}^{t} b(s)dB_s)^2 - \int_{0}^{t} b(s)^2ds
)$    $\forall t\in [0,1]$
 is a martingale. Where $b \in H^2(0,1)$ and for all $t\in [0,1], (\int_{0}^{t} b(s)dB_s)^2\in L^2(\Omega)$

my proof:
\begin{align}E(X_{t+1}|F_t)  
&= E((\int_{0}^{t+1} b(s)dB_s)^2 - \int_{0}^{t+1} b(s)^2ds
)|F_t)\\
&=(\int_{0}^{t} b(s)dB_s)^2 - \int_{0}^{t} b(s)^2ds
)+ E((\int_{0}^{1} b(s)dB_s)^2 - \int_{0}^{1} b(s)^2ds
)|F_t)\\
 &=X_t +E(\int_{0}^{1} b(s)dB_s)^2 - \int_{0}^{1} b(s)^2ds
)
\end{align}
Then since $H^2$ functions can be approximated by simple functions $g\in H_0^2$, we can write:

$$=X_t + +E(\int_{0}^{1} g(s)dB_s)^2 - \int_{0}^{1} g(s)^2ds)$$
By Iso Isometry this is equal to
$$ = X_t +\int_0^1Eg(s)^2 ds -  E(\int_{0}^{1} g(s)^2ds)$$

Can I then take the expectation inside the integral by Fubini's theorem and write:
$$ = X_t +\int_0^1Eg(s)^2 ds -  \int_{0}^{1} Eg(s)^2ds$$

$$=X_t$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Three things:

- Don't change the bounds on the integration, when you split the integral up use $\int_t^{t+1}$ because in general $b(0) \neq b(t)$
- Apply Ito Isometry directly to the second argument before you approximate with simple functions
- You shouldn't need to approximate with simple functions or use Fubini

Comment: when you say don't split the bounds of integration, are you suggesting I seperate the integral with indicator functions? Also doesn't Ito Isometry apply to simple processes only so I need the approximation?

Comment: Splitting integration should be as such: $\int_0^{t+1} \leftrightarrow \int_0^t + \int_t^{t+1}$. Ito Isometry works on square integrable processes so it works for both simple and non-simple processes.